# Checking if an object implements an interface with a generic <T> where the generic type is a child of T

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to check if a given object implements an interface I made that takes a generic parameter.

```
public interface ICaseCopier<T> where T : ModelElement 
{
    T Case1 { get; set; }
    T Case2 { get; set; }

    void CopyCase(T caseToCopy, T copiedCase);
}
```

One of my objects implements the interface like this:

```
public class ProcessLoad : ElectricalLoad, ICaseCopier<ProcessCase>
```

Where ProcessCase is a child of ModelElement. I have many objects that use that interface with different parameters in the generic, so checking them one by one is out of the question.

What I tried is this:

```
ICaseCopier<ModelElement> copier = this as ICaseCopier<ProcessCase>;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert source type 'ICaseCopier<ProcessCase>' to target type 'ICaseCopier<ModelElement>'
```

ProcessCase is castable to ModelElement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this since the conversion isn't safe - if it were you could do the following:

```
public class OtherElement : ModelElement { }

ICaseCopier<ModelElement> copier = this as ICaseCopier<ProcessCase>;
copier.Case1 = new OtherElement();
```

The only way you can do this is to make the `ICaseCopier<T>` interface covariant, which you can't do in its current form since `T` appears in both input and output positions.

Comment: I see, that makes sense... So the best approach would be to either replace the 'T' in my properties to 'ModelElement' or in the CopyCase method?

Comment: @AdamSmith - I'm not sure what you mean - if you mean make your interface non-generic, then that is one possibility. Otherwise you might be able to restructure your code to have a read-only interface and use some other mechanism to do the copying.

Comment: Thanks, I found what I was looking for after searching for "Covariant". Thanks for the answer!